# How can I duplicate values in a column?

Tags: excel

If I have a column with many different names of companies, how can I duplicate all values by a certain amount? For example, if I had a column with "Company A, Company B, Company C", how could I make it say "Company A, Company A, Company A, Company B, Company B, Company B, Company C, Company C, Company C"?

Comment: Copy it twice and sort?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original data is in column **A** and column **B** is empty, try this small macro:

```
Sub ThreeTimes()
    Dim N As Long, K As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "A").Copy Range(Cells(K, "B"), Cells(K + 2, "B"))
        K = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```